# Unity5. Почему коллайдер не на своем месте?

Tags: unity3d, объекты

У моего объекта в проекте случилось "нечто". Его коллайдер переехал в другое место. Заметил я это когда открыл проект для дальнейшего продолжения работы. Запустил его, чтобы протестить перед началом работы. И заметил что турелька не смотрит в мою сторону, хотя ее я уже давно не трогал. Внимательнее посмотрев на сцену я заметил, что коллайдер в другом месте. С одной стороны, я узнал что центр объекта не в центре объекта, а в центре объекта и коллайдера (смутное описание того чего я понял, но главное что я стал умнее  ). Ну, а с другой стороны я столкнулся с "нечто", что не могу объяснить. Если кто знает что это, расскажите, а то сверх интересно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Было бы неплохо показать ещё и иерархию сцены. Но, смею предположить, что вы где-то поменяли трансформ объекту, на котором висит коллайдер, а потом сохранили сцену.
Поясню. Башня - это 3d объект, значит в компонентах у вас обязательно был бы Mesh Renderer. т.к. я его не вижу здесь, могу предположить, что ваш объект - RedTuret является чайлдом объекта самой модельки.
Если хотите, чтобы они снова совпали - поставьте в компоненте Transform в поле Position все нули - для чайлдов это отклонение от мировой позиции родителя.
Если хотите чтобы коллайдер совпадал с моделькой, то перетащите все компоненты с этого объекта наружу по иерархии на объект, который собственно является башней.

Comment: Не думал что иерархия будет важна. Добавил иерархию. RedTuret является родительским объектом. И еще, на турельке стоит скрипт для наблюдения за танком. Но турелька не смотрит за танком, за танком смотрит коллайдер. Будто турель находится там где коллайдер, но ее там нет. Может это будет важно, не знаю, слишком много необъяснимого для меня.

Comment: @NormalBob, видимо, в скрипте поворот назначается не объекту, на котором висит скрипт, а объекту с коллайдером, либо вы скрипт повесили не на тот объект. Удалите объект с коллайдером - а вашему объекту-турельке добавьте сам компонент "коллайдер" и настройте его размеры, как вам нужно. Должно помочь :) коллайдеру не обязательно быть отдельным объектом.